# Two bitbucket (or Github) accounts with same SSH key

Tags: authentication, bitbucket

Bitbucket's help says:

> if your account's username is happy_cat, you would need to create a new account with a username of happycat to use this feature

That's my case, so I created a second account so that I can use the feature.

PROBLEM: I can't use this account with my SSH key, I am told:

> Someone has already registered that SSH key.

[image]

Using several SSH keys is a pain... is there a trick to make it work with the same SSH key?

(The exact same problem happens with Github)